# Local java application communicating with gwt browser app

Tags: java, gwt, browser

I have a local java app running on my machine.  I would like to send some string data over to my gwt browser app.  Is this possible without using the Java Robot class?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something similar at the moment, altough I want to make my GWT application to control a JAVA Robot on the client.

Take a look in [there](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx)

It seems that JavaFX allows for Communication between JavaScript and a Website in the JFX-WebEngine. Sadly, I haven't been able to test how this works with a GWT Application, as the Code is usually obfuscated and I don't know the proper GWT Code to perform that ATM:

```
class Bridge {
    public void exit() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
...
JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());
```

Sadly, I don't have the time to search for a proper Way to do that in GWT atm, too. But maybe you can find out something about this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)?
It allows to imitate a browser request

Comment: browser requests go to the server though, I need the data inside the browser itself.